# React CRA exposes the absolute path in the CSS build chunks?

Tags: css, reactjs, build, create-react-app

I'm kinda confused at the moment. I was analyzing the build outputs of my create-react-app application. Looking in the chunks I see that sometimes the code uses some absolute paths for some resources. e.g.

in main.a19b5211.chunk.css.map I can see:

```js
{"version":3,"sources":["/Users/my-pc-username/projects/my-app/folder/sass/bulma.sass"...
```

The built application works as should, there is no absolute path, neither my PC username in my whole project. But when I build the app then I see the following paths in the chunks.

Is it normal to have the whole absolute path exposed (aka your pc username) in the chunk files?

Comment: nope. What's your webpack output path?

Comment: just the standard ./build of the current project 